# Handling onOptionsItemSelected for both Navigation drawer and Action buttons

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer in one of my activities in Android. I have also added a couple of Action buttons and an action overflow to the action bar in the same activity. 
Now, the problem is with handling the select event for navigation drawer items, action buttons, and action overflow menu.
Currently, my `setOptionsItemSelected` looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
       return true;
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

How can I make it work for navigation item clicks, action button clicks, and action overflow menu clicks?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I made some modifications to my `onOptionsItemSelected` function and was able to make it work.
Here's the code for those who are facing the same problem:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // enabling drawer toggle by clicking on the app icon.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_refresh:
                    Log.d("ActionItemClicked", "Refresh clicked");
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_share:
                    Log.d("ActionItemClicked", "Share clicked");
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I hope it would help anyone stuck in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If ur xml file contains ListView like as shown below then u need to findViewById to listView in your navigation drawer activity and then  set its setItemSelectListener...
I don't know how have u implemented and designed ur navigation drawer ..so if this doesnt help please share ur code.. there is no relationship and dependency between actionbar and navigationdrawer

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">
        <fragment 
            android:name="com.example.juju.Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/maincontent"></fragment>
        <ListView 
            android:divider="@null"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What the below code is doing is enabling the navigationdrawer to open from actionbar from title.. for handling the items in actionbar and in overflow u have to implement it via onOptionItemSelected()..hope this clears everything..

```
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
           return true; 
       } 


   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: I have implemented navigation drawer using `ListView` and yes, I have implemented `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener` this way
`private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
   selectItem(position);
   
  }
     
 }`

Comment: I don't understand how to implement click listener for action buttons and overflows? Should I just replace the code in my current `onOptionsItemSelected` function with the sample code in Android developer's guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)?

Comment: I took your advice and modified the code to make it work. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59491/discussion-between-thestalker-and-basit-saeed).